# Removing the hashtag from AngularJS urls (#)

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

```
var app = angular.module('testing', ['onsen','ui.router']);


app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'myProfile'
    })


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

This way is not working...

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: http://localhost/mobileweb/#/home
I need to remove hash tag from the URL

Comment: The link @Damiano posted should help.

Comment: Did you checkout if there any console errors or so...which might be preventing `html5Mode` to work.

Answer (score 0):

what you have done is correct BUT you also need to add ...

```
  <base href="/">
```

to your HTML page

for more info about base tag see ...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp